# jsonix - How to create an element with prefix and without namespace?

Tags: namespaces, prefix, jsonix

I'm required to send an XML with the following elements:

```
<return>
    <getrooms>true</getrooms>
    <filters xmlns:a="http://some.com/xsd/atomicCondition" xmlns:c="http://some.com/xsd/complexCondition">
        <city></city>
        <country></country>
        <c:condition>
            <a:condition>
                <fieldname>fieldName</fieldname>
                <fieldtest>fieldTest</fieldtest>
                <fieldvalues>
                    <fieldvalue>fieldValue</fieldvalue>
                </fieldvalues>
            </a:condition>
            <operator>operator</operator>
            <a:condition>
                <fieldname>fieldName</fieldname>
                <fieldtest>fieldTest</fieldtest>
                <fieldvalues>
                    <fieldvalue>fieldValue</fieldvalue>
                 </fieldvalues>
            </a:condition>
         </c:condition>
    </filters>
    <resultsperpage></resultsperpage>
    <page></page>
</return>
```

I'm having difficulty forming the "c:condition" and "a:condition" Qname using Jsonix. Both Qname contains a Prefix but don't have the namespace.

My current code is:

```
{
    type: 'element',
    name: 'ccondition',
    elementName: {
        localPart: 'condition',
        prefix: 'c',
        namespaceURI: 'c'
    },
    typeInfo: 'DOXML.ComplexCondition'
},
```

This will result in the following:

`<c:condition xmlns:c="c">`

Anyone knows how to use Jsonix to generate the required Qname - "c:condition" that is without the namespaceURI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the prefix `c` is actually bound to the namespace `http://some.com/xsd/complexCondition` in this line:

`<filters xmlns:a="http://some.com/xsd/atomicCondition" xmlns:c="http://some.com/xsd/complexCondition">`

Both you prefixes `a` und `c` are bound to non-empty namespaces within the scope of the `filters` element.

So you should actually do:

`{
    type: 'element',
    name: 'ccondition',
    elementName: {
        localPart: 'condition',
        prefix: 'c',
        namespaceURI: 'http://some.com/xsd/complexCondition'
    },
    typeInfo: 'DOXML.ComplexCondition'
}`

I think you should be able to map to the empty namespace with `namespaceURI: ''`, but this is not what you need in your case, if I see it correctly.

Comment: Hi lexicore! Yup, that still ends in `<c:condition xmlns:c= " ">`, still don't match the XML format as provided above. The expected one is `<c:condition>`.

Comment: You seem to have ignored the part of my answer where I said that you actually have `xmlns:c="http://some.com/xsd/complexCondition"` here. You therefore should use `namespaceURI: 'http://some.com/xsd/complexCondition'`.

Comment: Hi @lexicore I don't understand what you mean by  using `namespaceURI: 'http://some.com/xsd/complexCondition'` and then mapping it with `namespaceURI: ''` . Following the below  

`{
    type: 'element',
    name: 'ccondition',
    elementName: {
        localPart: 'condition',
        prefix: 'c',
        namespaceURI: 'http://some.com/xsd/complexCondition'
    },
    typeInfo: 'DOXML.ComplexCondition'
}`
The result will be `<c:condition xmlns:c= "http://some.com/xsd/complexCondition ">`

Comment: Using context to add in the `namespaceURI` to `<filters>`, Jsonix still don't allow `namespaceURI=''`

Comment: *and then mapping it with* I never said "and then". I said you should be able to use empty namespace (`namespaceURI: ''`) and that is not what you want.

Comment: *The result will be `<c:condition xmlns:c="http://some.com/xsd/complexCondition">`* - correct and this is what you effectively have in your XML example. In your XML example the namespace prefix `c` is bound to `http://some.com/xsd/complexCondition`. So this result is correct in respect to your XML example.

Comment: Thank you! I got what you mean now. I stumbled to another problem. I will update the main question.